# Pytube set Resolution

Tags: python, pytube

I can download Videos with this code with Pytube:

```
from pytube import Youtube
Youtube('youryoutubelink').streams.first().download()
```

But when I open the Video, it is very low resolution. I want to have 720p/1080p.
How can I set this in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you are downloading the first one of the available streams which is usually 720p. To download a 360p resolution stream, you can do:

```
YouTube('https://youtu.be/2lAe1cqCOXo').streams.filter(res="360p").first().download()
```

Note: this is `YouTube`, not Youtube.

**Short explanation:**
You need to use `filter()` to choose a specific resolution you want to download. For example, if you call:

```
yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/2lAe1cqCOXo')
```

it returns the available stream to `yt`. You can view all the streams by typing:

```
yt.streams
```

You can filter which type of filter you want. To filter only 360p streams you can write:

```
yt.streams.filter(res="360p")
```

To filter only 360p streams and download the first one type this:

```
yt.streams.filter(res="360p").first().download()
```

Comment: I've used your code but the downloaded video has no audio. So I used `yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()` and it works!

Answer (score 5):

In this method you can download the available highest resolution video.

```
video = YouTube('mylink')
highresvid = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
highresvid.download('location')
```